# Modify csv with groovy

Tags: groovy

Newbie need help with Groovy. I want to modify the next .csv:

```
Agency Name:IKEA,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Advertiser Name: Ingka,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Campaign Name:All,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Date Resolution:Days,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Campaign Dates:N/A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Date Range:Last X Days (25.06.2020 - 01.07.2020),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Creation Date: 02.07.2020 5:26:18 (GMT -5 Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,,,,,,,,,

You must save the report locally to create a pivot table based on the report data.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Advertiser Name,Advertiser ID,Campaign Name,Campaign ID,Date,Site Name,Site ID,Device Type,Placement Name,Placement ID,Clickthrough URL,* Clicks,* Served Impressions,* Total Recordable Impressions (IAB),* Total Viewable Impressions (IAB)
Ingka,190530,1_flight_0119,947535,25.06.2020,Auditorius SE,101304,Smart Phone,Flight_EK_Auditorius_Video_mobile,27353235,https://www.ikea.com/promo/wifi?utm_source=Auditorius&utm_medium=Video_mobile,0,0,0,0
Ingka,190530,1_flight_0119,947535,28.06.2020,Between Exchange SE,124598,PC,Flight_IQP_Between_Exchange_Banner_728x90_DCO,27359134,,0,0,0,0
Data was updated last on 7/2/2020 12:00:00 AM (GMT -5 Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Viewability mode is set per individual campaign,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

What I want:

1. Remove these lines:

```
Agency Name:IKEA,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Advertiser Name: Ingka,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Campaign Name:All,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Date Resolution:Days,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Campaign Dates:N/A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Date Range:Last X Days (25.06.2020 - 01.07.2020),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Creation Date: 02.07.2020 5:26:18 (GMT -5 Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,,,,,,,,,

You must save the report locally to create a pivot table based on the report data.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

2. Remove these lines:

```
Data was updated last on 7/2/2020 12:00:00 AM (GMT -5 Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Viewability mode is set per individual campaign,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

3. Change headers names.

To: `AdvertiserName,AdvertiserID,CampaignName,CampaignID,ReportDate,Site,SiteID,Device,PlacementName,PlacementID,URL,Clicks,Impressions,TotalRecordableImpressions,TotalViewableImpressions`

After reading some topics about parsing CSV in groovy I tried with:

```
def reader = new StringReader('''...''') //or FileReader/InputStream/whatever
def mapList = []

reader.splitEachLine(','){ parts ->
   mapList << [ 
        AdvertiserName:parts[0], 
        AdvertiserID:parts[1], 
        CampaignName:parts[2], 
        CampaignID:parts[3], 
        ReportDate:parts[4],
        Site:parts[5],
        SiteID:parts[6],
        Device:parts[7],
        PlacementName:parts[8],
        PlacementID:parts[9],
        URL:parts[10],
        Clicks:parts[11],
        Impressions:parts[12],
        TotalRecordableImpressions:parts[13],
        TotalViewableImpressions:parts[14]
    ]
}

def result = mapList.findAll{ it.value!=null }
```

But it returns empty map, when mapList contains records with non null values:

```
[AdvertiserName:Ingka, AdvertiserID:190530, CampaignName:1_flight_0119, CampaignID:947535, ReportDate:25.06.2020, Site:Auditorius SE, SiteID:101304, Device:Smart Phone, PlacementName:Flight_EK_Auditorius_Video_mobile, PlacementID:27353235, URL:https://www.ikea.com/promo/wifi?utm_source=Auditorius&utm_medium=Video_mobile, Clicks:0, Impressions:0, TotalRecordableImpressions:0, TotalViewableImpressions:0]
```

Because it's a list with maps. I tried to fix it with:

```
mapList.collectEntries() {
    [it.AdvertiserName, it.AdvertiserID, ...]
}
```

But it also returns smth weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something straight-forward:

```
def str ='''\
Agency Name:IKEA,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Advertiser Name: Ingka,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Campaign Name:All,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Date Resolution:Days,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Campaign Dates:N/A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Date Range:Last X Days (25.06.2020 - 01.07.2020),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Creation Date: 02.07.2020 5:26:18 (GMT -5 Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,,,,,,,,,

You must save the report locally to create a pivot table based on the report data.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Advertiser Name,Advertiser ID,Campaign Name,Campaign ID,Date,Site Name,Site ID,Device Type,Placement Name,Placement ID,Clickthrough URL,* Clicks,* Served Impressions,* Total Recordable Impressions (IAB),* Total Viewable Impressions (IAB)
Ingka,190530,1_flight_0119,947535,25.06.2020,Auditorius SE,101304,Smart Phone,Flight_EK_Auditorius_Video_mobile,27353235,https://www.ikea.com/promo/wifi?utm_source=Auditorius&utm_medium=Video_mobile,0,0,0,0
Ingka,190530,1_flight_0119,947535,28.06.2020,Between Exchange SE,124598,PC,Flight_IQP_Between_Exchange_Banner_728x90_DCO,27359134,,0,0,0,0
Data was updated last on 7/2/2020 12:00:00 AM (GMT -5 Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Viewability mode is set per individual campaign,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
'''

def headers = [ 'AdvertiserName', 'AdvertiserID', 'CampaignName', 'CampaignID', 'ReportDate', 'Site',
               'SiteID', 'Device', 'PlacementName', 'PlacementID', 'URL', 'Clicks', 'Impressions',
               'TotalRecordableImpressions', 'TotalViewableImpressions' ].withIndex()

def list = []
boolean start
str.splitEachLine(','){ parts ->
  if( 'Advertiser Name' == parts[ 0 ] ){
    start = true
    return
  }else if( !start || 15 != parts.size() ) return

  list << headers.collectEntries{ [ it[ 0 ], parts[ it[ 1 ] ] ] }
}

println list.join( '\n' )
```

prints:

```
[AdvertiserName:Ingka, AdvertiserID:190530, CampaignName:1_flight_0119, CampaignID:947535, ReportDate:25.06.2020, Site:Auditorius SE, SiteID:101304, Device:Smart Phone, PlacementName:Flight_EK_Auditorius_Video_mobile, PlacementID:27353235, URL:https://www.ikea.com/promo/wifi?utm_source=Auditorius&utm_medium=Video_mobile, Clicks:0, Impressions:0, TotalRecordableImpressions:0, TotalViewableImpressions:0]
[AdvertiserName:Ingka, AdvertiserID:190530, CampaignName:1_flight_0119, CampaignID:947535, ReportDate:28.06.2020, Site:Between Exchange SE, SiteID:124598, Device:PC, PlacementName:Flight_IQP_Between_Exchange_Banner_728x90_DCO, PlacementID:27359134, URL:, Clicks:0, Impressions:0, TotalRecordableImpressions:0, TotalViewableImpressions:0]
```

To put the data back into a file you would need smth like:

```
def file = new StringWriter() // replace with new File( '../output.csv' )
file.withWriter{ out ->
  out << headers*.first().join( ',' )
  list.each{
    out << '\n' << it.values().join( ',' )
  }
}
file
```

prints:

```
AdvertiserName,AdvertiserID,CampaignName,CampaignID,ReportDate,Site,SiteID,Device,PlacementName,PlacementID,URL,Clicks,Impressions,TotalRecordableImpressions,TotalViewableImpressions
Ingka,190530,1_flight_0119,947535,25.06.2020,Auditorius SE,101304,Smart Phone,Flight_EK_Auditorius_Video_mobile,27353235,https://www.ikea.com/promo/wifi?utm_source=Auditorius&utm_medium=Video_mobile,0,0,0,0
Ingka,190530,1_flight_0119,947535,28.06.2020,Between Exchange SE,124598,PC,Flight_IQP_Between_Exchange_Banner_728x90_DCO,27359134,,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Great!
But how to pack these maps back to .csv like format? As I can see, each map in this list = each line in .csv, and each key in these maps are common headers for all lines.